# how to fetch the value from an object in ts?

Tags: angular

How to fetch the values from an object? 
Response is of type `object.Response` has the `Email`,`password` and `Role`.

I tried of taking value using `object.value` but not working.

```
 this.service.login(loginModel).subscribe((response) => {


      if (response != null && this.Role == "1") {

        sessionStorage.setItem('email', this.email)
        this.route.navigateByUrl("/employee/employee-dashboard")
      }
```

Expected output is `response.Role` should return value. Please click the image link for console.log(response)

[Image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jqHJ.png)

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(response)`?

Comment: I think you simply need: `if (response != null && response.Role == "1") {}`

Comment: You mean ```if (response && response.Role === "1") {}```. Let's get truthy and falsy right

Comment: @PrashantPimpale please see the image

Comment: @Arne it is showing role does not exist on the type object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You kinda leave us to guess what your console log outputs. But let's assume your "response" object has the properties "Role", "Email", and "Password" (which by the way violates the code style guidelines; properties should be lower case; but let's ignore that for now). If your "response" object has those properties, you can simply receive them using `response.Email`, `response.Role` and `response.Password`.

By the way, if you only care about the email and want to filter by role, you could use:

```
this.service.login(loginModel).pipe(
   filter(user => user && user.Role === "1"),
   pluck('Email')
)subscribe(email => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('email', email)
        this.route.navigateByUrl("/employee/employee-dashboard")
      }
```

The filter operator filters your observable stream, in this case for role existing (being truthy) and being equal to 1. Then you take only the "Email" property using the pluck operator; and you're all set.

Comment: Please see the image description.

Comment: The image doesn't tell me anything to be honest. Yeah, some console output. But where is the console.log in your code example? What is it outputting? The value of ```response```? And what about that array? Where does that come from?

Comment: Basically it is an api call. The value of response is showing in console.

Comment: How to fetch the value of role?

Comment: What's the result of ```console.log(response)```?

Comment: {Email: "vinayak@gmail.com", Password: "vinayak", Role: "2"}
Email: "vinayak@gmail.com"
Password: "vinayak"
Role: "2"
__proto__: Object

Comment: Okay, and ```console.log(response.Role)```?

Comment: same as in the image. Image is the output of console.log(response)

Comment: it is returning 2. But ide is showing "the property Role does not exist on the type 'Object' "